# How can I calculate the difference in text blocks via JavaScript / jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 blocks of text.. I want to see what the difference percentage is between them. How can I do this?

Comment: And what have you tried? What went wrong?

Answer (score 5):

That depends, what is your definition of difference? Do you want to use the [levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) or something else?

You can find some implementations of the levenshtein algorithm in javascript [here](http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/6942) and [here](http://www.mgilleland.com/ld/ldjavascriptsource.htm). You could convert the outcome of the levenshtein distance to a percentage with the following calculation:

```
percentage = 100 * (levenshtein distance) / (total number of characters)
```

Answer (score 1):

Well getting the content of the text boxes is easy, just use the $.html (or $.val for form controls like textarea elements) function.

For comparing the strings, you'll need to use a string analysis algorithm like [Levenshtein Distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) to work out how different the strings are, and then use the length of the blocks of text to work out a percentage.

Hopefully that will give you a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

PHP's `similar_text()` can do this, and `phpJS` has created the [JS port](http://phpjs.org/functions/similar_text:902) of it.

See also: [levenshtein()](http://phpjs.org/functions/levenshtein:463) and [soundex()](http://phpjs.org/functions/soundex:520)

Answer (score 0):

Depends what you're differentiating. http://fiddle.jshell.net/G9ghG/2/